# How to get a list of available TeamProjects through EnvDTE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I was able to list the workspaces but i didn't find code examples on how to have information about the Source Control Team Projects.
I've looked through MSDN Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.aspx) but didn't succeed to get a List of Team Projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to list Team Projects of Source Control you cannot use the Visual Studio SDK but you need the Team Foundation Server SDK. Take a look at the following samples to get Team Project and other information from TFS.

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/01/25/how-to-get-the-tfs-objects-used-in-our-own-ui-integration.aspx

Comment: I wanted to get the **Current** Workspace and Current TeamProjects without asking the user another login/authentication to TFS.

Comment: Take a look at the second link about current context usage. Hope it helps

Comment: I will try that and let you know